# Selenium can't find any elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some elements of Quora. When I run the following code, the browser opens correctly and goes to the right page (requires a Quora account), however pretty much anything I search for returns an empty list. For example, Selenium does not find a single link ('a' tag). However when I explore the DOM of the page opened by Selenium, I do find plenty of 'a' tags, 'div' tags, the classes I'm looking for, etc.

What is happening here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

main_url="https://www.quora.com/profile/Joseph-Boyle"

def startBrowser():
    driver = webdriver.Ie()
    #driver = webdriver.Edge()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
    #driver.get(main_url+"/following")
    return driver

def get_all_following(driver,url):
    driver.get(url+"/following")
    a=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    #b=driver.find_element_by_class_name('PagedList UserConnectionsFollowingList')
    #c=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    print len(a)
    #print len(b)
    #print len(c)

driver=startBrowser()
get_all_following(driver,main_url)
```

Comment: I used `webdriver.Chrome()` instead of `webdriver.Ie()` and it shows me 420 div tags. Did you try the Chrome webdriver?

Comment: For some reason, Chrome does work indeed. Thanks.